# Match by argument pattern and left join

Tags: r, regex, merge, left-join

I am trying to match city/county names (fortunately information on state names are provided) with their corresponding state names and then append their first three phone digit as another column using `left_join()`. My initial thought would be to replicate the city/county name column and then replacing them with their state names using `sapply()` along with `grep()`, then using `left_join()` to merge it with phone digit column, but it doesn't seem that my code works.

```css
library(dplyr)

location <- data.frame(location = c('Asortia, New York', 'Buffalo, New York', 'New York, New York',  'Alexandra, Virginia', 'Fairfax, Virginia', 'Baltimore, Maryland', 'Springfield, Maryland'), number = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700))

state <- data.frame(state = c('New York', 'Virginia', 'Maryland'))

sapply(as.character(state$state), function(i) grep(i, location$location))

### doesn't work! ###
### my desired output would be ###

  location number
1 New York    100
2 New York    200
3 New York    300
4 Virginia    400
5 Virginia    500
6 Maryland    600
7 Maryland    700
```

Such that I could use `left_join` to merge the output generated from above with their three digit phone number. For example,

```css
df <- location
names(df)[1] <- 'state'
digit <- data.frame(state = c('New York', 'Virginia', 'Maryland'), digit = c(212, 703, 410))
   
new_df <- left_join(df, digit, by = 'state')

### the desired output ###

  location number digit
1 New York    100   212
2 New York    200   212
3 New York    300   212
4 Virginia    400   703
5 Virginia    500   703
6 Maryland    600   410
7 Maryland    700   410
```

I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100958/replacing-data-values-based-on-grep-result-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156927/replace-column-values-by-grep-in-r) thread, but didn't quite get the clue.
Hope someone could help me on this.

##  Update

I found that using `grepl` in a `for loop` also works, but the processing may be slow if you have large amount of data (the data I'm working on has two million observations).

```css
for (i in state$state) { 
location$location[grepl(i, location$location)] <- i
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we can use `str_remove` by `paste`ing (`str_c`) the `pattern` vector in 'state' column from 'state' dataset as a regex lookaround to match anything that precedes the vector (to remove)

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
location %>%
    mutate(location = str_remove(location, str_c(".*(?=(",
            str_c(state$state, collapse  = "|"), "))")))
#  location number
#1 New York    100
#2 New York    200
#3 New York    300
#4 Virginia    400
#5 Virginia    500
#6 Maryland    600
#7 Maryland    700
```

---

Or another option is to `separate` into two column and remove the `first`

```
library(tidyr)
location %>%
   separate(location, into = c('unwanted', 'location'), sep=",\\s*") %>% 
   select(-unwanted)
```

---

Or if we have a specific pattern, remove the prefix part by matching one or more characters that are not a `,` from the start (`^`) followed by `,` and zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) as pattern in the `str_remove`

```
location %>% 
    mutate(location = str_remove(location, '^[^,]+,\\s*'))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I actually want to remove the city/county names but retain the state names (and without the ",").

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helps.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but your answer really helps.

Comment: I found that using `grepl` in a `for loop` to replace original entries also works, but the processing may be slow if you have large amount of data.

Comment: @ChrisT.  You can replace with `stri_detect` from `stringi`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_match`, `map`, and `unite`:

```
library(tidyverse)

location$state <- map_df(state, ~str_match(location$location, .x)) %>% 
                  unite("state", na.rm=T) %>% 
                  pull()

left_join(location, digit, by = "state") %>% 
  select(state, number, digit)

     state number digit
1 New York    100   212
2 New York    200   212
3 New York    300   212
4 Virginia    400   703
5 Virginia    500   703
6 Maryland    600   410
7 Maryland    700   410
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very neat.